# using date as key value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i am working on a simple attendance system which should be having structure like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a800c280856ed210f6553cb"),
    "class" : 1,
    "subject" : {
        "maths" : {
            "grammer" : "0",
            "spelling" : "0",
            "marks" : 25
        },
        "science" : {
            "grammer" : "1",
            "spelling" : "1",
            "marks" : 21
        },
        "history" : {
            "grammer" : "1",
            "spelling" : "1",
            "marks" : 28
        }
    },
    "name" : "max",
    "roll no" : 10
}
```

what i am trying to do is to create another field of attendance  as show below

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a800c280856ed210f6553cb"),
        "class" : 1,
        "subject" : {
            "maths" : {
                "grammer" : "0",
                "spelling" : "0",
                "marks" : 25
            },
            "science" : {
                "grammer" : "1",
                "spelling" : "1",
                "marks" : 21
            },
            "history" : {
                "grammer" : "1",
                "spelling" : "1",
                "marks" : 28
            }
        },
        "name" : "max",
        "roll no" : 10
        "attendace":{"Tue Feb 11 2018 12:14:36 GMT+0530 (IST)": 1,
                     "Tue Feb 12 2018 12:14:36 GMT+0530 (IST)": 1, 
                     "Tue Feb 13 2018 12:14:36 GMT+0530 (IST)": 1
                     }

    }
```

i tried the following command but its not working

```
db.candidates.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5a800c280856ed210f6553cb") },{$set : {"attendance":{Date():1}}})
```

any help is much appreciated

Regards Saif

Comment: Try `db.candidates.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5a800c280856ed210f6553cb") },{$push : {"attendance":new Date()}})`

Comment: i tried your way but what i want is  date in  place of key value like this 

  `"attendace":{"Tue Feb 11 2018 12:14:36 GMT+0530 (IST)": 1,
                     "Tue Feb 12 2018 12:14:36 GMT+0530 (IST)": 1, 
                     "Tue Feb 13 2018 12:14:36 GMT+0530 (IST)": 1
                     }`

Comment: Keep the values as key value pair. It will help you with updates and query operation.